# Is there any standard format for engine agnostic 2D tilemaps?

Tags: tilemap, standards

Basically that. I tried searching for standard 2D tilemaps formats or encodings, but I haven't found anything significative. I know that big engines use their own formats (Godot Resources, for example) but I think it would be interesting to have a common ground in case you want to use third party applications to edit/generate/process/etc your tilemaps.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/927/ If your game is big enough, the community is happy to figure out how to work with it. If your game is small and you want to have it editable, either provide a really good documentation or provide a map editor right away to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the closest you're likely to get is [Tiled](https://www.mapeditor.org/)'s [TMX format](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/stable/reference/tmx-map-format/).

Many games will use Tiled as a map authoring tool and use [import plugins for various](https://github.com/Seanba/SuperTiled2Unity) [engines](https://github.com/vnen/godot-tiled-importer) to import those maps at development time.

Usually though, this is a developer-only workflow, not something that ships as part of the distributed game binary for modders to use in modifying/adding maps.

Tiled is mainly useful for laying out the base visuals of a game map, not the game logic or other custom/dynamic content the game might need, so those parts are frequently added in the game engine the game is being authored in - leading to what you've observed about game maps being saved as Godot Resources, Unity Scenes, etc. rather than a cross-engine format.